# reconfiguring wacom eraser tool for photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, wacom

I have a Wacom Intuos 3 more than a decade old. The pen nib has been worn down to nothing but still works. I dont think I can get it out anymore since it is basically flat. The eraser tool works great and it has pressure settings of its own.
I was wondering if there is a way to hack the pen such that the eraser would work as a brush for painting in Photoshop?
Right now if I flip the pen it just switches to the eraser tool by default. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can [**replace nibs**](https://us-store.wacom.com/Product/pro-accessory-kit-for-previous-generation-tablets-and-displays#/undefined1).. I'm sure you could pull the old one out if you tried enough.

You can also just [**replace the Stylus**](https://us-store.wacom.com/Catalog/Accessories/Pens/grip-pen#/undefined1). I believe the Intuos 3, 4, 5, and Pro are all using similar radio frequencies. I know I've swapped and mingled styluses between tablet versions several times. You can call Wacom to verify though. They are always happy to help with questions.

As far as I'm aware, the eraser end is *always* seen as the eraser end. You can change the function of it to something *other* than an eraser, such as a key stroke, or click....

[image]

.....but you *can't* make it operate like the nib end.

<sub>The screen shot is from the Mac preferences for my Intuos 5 (the Art Pen specifically). As far as I remember, it's had similar options for the eraser end since the Intuos 1 was released. I've been a Wacom user since the first-gen Intuos.</sub>

Comment: I don't think I can pull this out. Its just completely flattened. Tried using a nail clipper but to no avail.  I am hoping someone has some secret hack for making the eraser work as a brush.  I am considering buying a new one otherwise but it is a bit expensive.

Comment: Use a sewing needle or very small screw.. drive it into the tip's center and then pull it out. You can also unscrew the tip cover which may provide an extra millimeter or two for gripping it.

Comment: I guess I could try that. That wouldn't damage the pen in anyway would it?

Comment: Well if you can't use it.. does it matter? But no it shouldn't. Don't use *massive* force driving in a needle/or screw, gently work it into the plastic nib, that's all.  Heck, even **heat up** a needle so it melts the nib plastic and goes in easier.. let it cool, then pull it out, the Nib should come out with it.

Comment: No I can still use the pen. However over the last six months or so the pen began to stick. It would still remain clicked even when I lifted the pen and it was hovering. I read a suggestion to take the nib out and leave it out overnight. However since my nib has been worn to nothing and its pretty much unextractable I was looking for an alternative solution to salvage the pen. I guess I'll just buy a new one if that is not available.

Comment: An Intuos 3 has got to be 15-20 years old now... if the internal spring is sticking on the stylus, you need a new stylus. After more than a decade it shouldn't be surprising that hardware wears out. It happens to all of us eventually. Just count yourself lucky that you can merely replace the stylus and not the entire tablet.

Comment: It is quite old. This problem has only been happening for about 6-8 months.  I guess I'll just get a replacement. For anyone who has this worn down nib problem there is this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9zYiwXvKv0. Thanks for all the replies

Comment: HA! Exactly what I suggested :)